# Path Parameter in UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: for XCAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, xcasset

Is there any way to retrieve a UIImage object with `imageWithContentsOfFile:` if the image is stored in an [xcasset](/questions/tagged/xcasset) Bundle (Xcode 5 Image Catalog)?

It's easy to access it with the `imageNamed:` method, but `imageWithContentsOfFile:` has a slightly different behavior, so what do I pass in the path parameter?

I've tried to use a variety of formats, but they all return a `nil` value:

- ImageName@2x.png
- ImageName@2x
- ImageName
- NSBundle File Path to Image

Apple's documentation doesn't specify a format for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a good answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't load an image from xcasset via `imageWithContentsOfFile:`, because every entry in xcasset is compiled into a single binary file `Assets.car`. The format of this file is not documented and yet not reverse-engeneered well afaik (see ["What you should know if you want to try reverse-engineering this stuff." section](https://github.com/davepeck/iOS-artwork) for explanations).

This is done for performance and low memory consume reasons, that's why `imageNamed:` is a good solution.